# is there way to get cookies unique ID?

Tags: database, session, cookies, cart, shopping-cart

I trying to create a shopping cart where user will be able to add to cart without needed to login.

I have 3 ways to do this:

Session - this works but issue is that soon as they close the website... then session will get destroy

Cookie - This fixes the session issue but cookies have small size limit and user can block it also

DataBase - I can store cart in database for 3 days and manual remove the record in database

I like the database solution but there is a issue. how can I get unquite ID of user who is not logged in?

I could use session to get unquie id but than if user close website.. re-open website than his session ID will change also.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FingerPrintJS2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) for your case.